# Two clocks, different times

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, bugs, clock

The clock in the lockscreen shows the right time, but the one on the right corner of the status bar gets stuck. It shows the right time when I turn the mobile on, but then at some point it stops and stays at whatever time it was showing at that moment.

What could be happening? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: One for the local time for your time zone the other for another time zone may be?

Comment: Not both clocks have to display same time, what will be the point?

Comment: @esQmo_ I edited the question to clarify the problem.

Comment: What device is that?

Comment: @esQmo_ Blu Studio XL2